# if two variables are correlated with each other, how to estimate the true impact of one of them (in presence of other) with the target variable

Tags: regression, correlation, feature-selection, regression-coefficients, lasso

I am trying to predict a continuous variable using 5 predictors. Two of the five predictors (say A,B) are correlated to each other. A is the most important variable out of the 5 for prediction. Since A is included in the model B is not being selected as a predictor variable (in lasso) and also the permutation importance of B is 0 (since A explains everything that B can explain).

However, B is an important variable in my business problem and I wanted to understand the impact of B on the target. Are there any way/methods to find out true impact of B on the target.

Comment: First, don't let the software make your decisions for you.  If you know B should be included in the model, *then include it.* Second, in a typical multiple regression model there is no unique way to attribute some portion of "impact" to each explanatory variable. Thus, to make any progress you need to decide (1) how you want to quantify "impact" and (2) what assumptions to make about the values of all other explanatory variables when you vary B to assess its impact.

Comment: thanks @whuber. I used GLM(-ve binomial) as target is counts. In GLM B is significant (p value =0) and +ve coefficient, also A is significant too. But in permutation importance with xgboost, B is not importance. (1) by quantifying, I wanted to know if B has a +ve or -ve effect on target. Though B is +ve as per GLM and coefficient significant, because of its correlation with A (corr = 0.4) and permutation importance weight =0 I don't know if it's really +ve on target (or it is +ve because of correlation). (2) assumptions - all else being same impact of B (but cannot do that as A is correlated)